# Does YouTube allow use of the API on Apple TV apps?

Tags: youtube-api, tvos, apple-tv

I would like to build an Apple TV (TVOS) app but I see very little documentation on it. Do you allow YouTube videos on the apple TV?

We would like to use the YouTube API to pull videos into the App.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: That sounds like a good question for Youtube's developer support